# Replace a loop in python with the equivalent of a matlab find

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Assume I have a sorted array of tuples which is sorted by the first value. I want to find the first index where a condition on the first element of the tuple holds. i.e. How do I replace the following code

```
test_array = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),)(9,10)]
min_value = 5
index = 0
for c in test_array:
        if c[0] > min_value:
           break
        else:
            index = index + 1
```

With the equivalent of a matlab find ?

i.e. At the end of this loop I expect to get 3 but I'd like to make this more efficient. I an fine with using numpy for this. I tried using argmax but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: Don't you mean you want to find the _last_ index where the condition holds, rather than the first? Because that's what you're doing here. Can you add a brief example of how you would do this in matlab so we can better understand what you're asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the list is sorted and if you know the max possible value for the second element (or if there can only be 1 element with the same first value), you could apply `bisect` on the list of tuples (returns the sorted insertion position in the list)

```
import bisect
test_array = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10)]
min_value = 5

print(bisect.bisect_left(test_array,(min_value,10000)))
```

Hardcoding to 10000 is bad, so if you only have integers you can do that instead:

```
print(bisect.bisect_left(test_array,(min_value+1,)))
```

result: `3`

if you had floats (also works with integers) you could use `sys.float_info.epsilon` like this:

```
print(bisect.bisect_left(test_array,(min_value*(1+sys.float_info.epsilon),)))
```

It has `O(log(n))` complexity so it's much better than a simple `for` loop when there are a lot of elements.

Comment: I did not know about bisect. Excellent! Thanks.

Comment: yes, that's a good one. See my edit. Depending on the data, my previous answer could fail.

Comment: It appears you can use None as the second parameter instead of 1000 as well.

Comment: not in python 3 you can't `unorderable types: NoneType() < int()`. But without element it works (but it's minimum value, not maximum): `>>> (5,) < (5,-30000)
yields True`

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy to indicate the elements that obey the conditions and then use `argmax()`, to get the index of the first one

```
import numpy
test_array = numpy.array([(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8),(9,10)])
min_value = 5

print (test_array[:,0]>min_value).argmax()
```

if you would like to find all of the elements that obey the condition, use can replace `argmax()` by `nonzero()[0]`

Comment: I'd say this is overkill

Comment: I would like the index where the condition holds. Further, this returned (3,4). I want to return the index of (7,8). Thanks

Comment: @jphollowed, what do you mean by overkill? That's a simple one line solution.

Comment: @user2476373 Just because numpy isn't necessary for something you can do trivially with python builtins. But more so because `nonzero()` is doing more than is needed. I don't consider it clean coding to immediately index the return of a function because you only even need part of it. Might as well use a more appropriate tool

Comment: @jphollowed, Thanks for the feedback. I edited the answer and replaced nonzero with argmax, and now it makes the solution cleaner. Re libraries, I disagree with you. I don't see a difference between `import bisect` as the accepted answer or `import numpy` as in this answer. I think numpy is preferable since it makes the code more concise, readble and in many times, faster

Answer (score 0):

In general, numpy's `where` is used in a fashion similar to MATLAB's `find`. However, from an efficiency standpoint, I `where` cannot be controlled to return only the first element found. So, from a computational perspective, what you're doing here is not arguably less inefficient.

The `where` equivalent would be

```
index = numpy.where(numpy.array([t[0] for t in test_array]) >= min_value)
index = index[0] - 1
```