# Python - binary search in sorted list of lists

Tags: python, list, sorting, search

Is it a way in Python 3 to binary search in sorted list of lists?

 Let's assume I have a list of lists:

```
list = [['A', 'B', 3], ['C', 'D', 1], ['E', 'F', 2]]
```

I've sorted it by 3d element in inner list with:

```
list = sorted(list , key=itemgetter(2))
```

and now list is

```
[['C', 'D', 1], ['E', 'F', 2], ['A', 'B', 3]]
```

And now how can I search in this sorted list with binary search (O(log(n)) time complexity) using element from inner list by which sorting was done?
Like

```
findBy(list, index_of_inner_list, value_of_inner_list_to_find)
```

Outer list is huge. Inner lists have len 50. And I need to make many queries to extract some elements from outer list based on condition related to inner lists. I was thinking about `bisect` but inner arrays would be a problem for it I think.

Comment: Have you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42146482/using-bisect-on-list-of-tuples-but-compare-using-first-value-only where there are several suggestions for bisect implementations with an arbitrary key function.

Comment: Look at the last example on the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/bisect.html#other-examples) doc page. Does that look like what you're going for?

Comment: @glibdud That example constructs a new list from the keys which destroys the `O(log_N)` performance of bisect which the OP explicitly asks for.

Comment: @glibdud Yes, I've read that and I was wondering is it a better way in Python for things like I need. Something like Comparator in Java.

Comment: @aleksei I've the exact same question, what did you end up doing?