# Using bisect in a list of tuples with checking both element of tuple?

Tags: python, bisect

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42146482/using-bisect-on-list-of-tuples-but-compare-using-first-value-only) about how to use bisect on a list of tuples and only compare the first value of tuple. It works, but how can I compare two value? if index of x < index of y and y[0] <= x[0] or y[1] <= x[1], bisect.bisect_left return index
like

```
input:[(2, 2), (3, 1), (5, 6)]
bisect.bisect_left(input, (2, 3)) => 0
bisect.bisect_left(input, (3, 4)) => 1
bisect.bisect_left(input, (5, 5)) => 2
```

Comment: sorry.. not sure why i post the wrong link

Answer (score 1):

Bisect requires a sorted list.  It will process tuples properly if the sorted order matches the comparison result between tuple entries.

This corresponds to `x[0]<y[0] or x[0]==y[0] and x[1]<y[1]`.

Since you cannot sort your tuples on both values simultaneously, it will be impossible to obtain a `y[0] <= x[0] or y[1] <= x[1]` bisection result. Even if some combination of data allowed the sort, there would always be the possibility that a tuple (a,b) has two indexes in the list which constitutes an ambiguous result.